# How do I wrap untagged text elements using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

For example I have a html string:

```
<span class="no">1172</span><span class="r">case</span> primary_key_prefix_type
```

How to wrap every element which doesn't have tag by Nokogiri like this:

```
<span class="no">1172</span><span class="r">case</span> <span>primary_key_prefix_type</span>
```

Comment: Your terminology is a little bit off. Am I correct in understanding that, given an arbitrary root element (perhaps a `<p>` or a `<body>`) you want to find every whitespace-delimited-word (text node) that is a child of that element and wrap a span around it, but leave every other _element_ alone?

Comment: 'primary_key_prefix_type' doesn't have tag at all, and I want to wrap by span tag like here: <span>primary_key_prefix_type</span>

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how a parser views the HTML. Your `primary_key_prefix_type` is wrapped by a tag, it's just not the tags on that line. Parsers don't *really* care about lines, they care about the hierarchical structure of the document. So, whatever contains `<span class="no">1172</span><span class="r">case</span> primary_key_prefix_type` contains that text, and is what you should be changing if you're going to use CSS.

Comment: In JavaScript I can get that untagged element by 'nextSibling'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't feel like the most elegant solution, but it works:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

# Given a node, find each whitespace-delimited word
# and wrap it in the supplied markup
def wrap_text( node, wrapper='<span />' )
  wrapper = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(wrapper).children.first
  node.xpath('child::text()').each do |text_node|
    text_node.swap( text_node.text.gsub(/(\s*)(\S+)(\s*)/) do
      "#{$1}#{
        wrapper.clone.tap{ |w| w.inner_html = $2 }.to_html
      }#{$3}"
    end )
  end
  node
end    

# Testing
html = Nokogiri::HTML '<body>
  <p><span class="no">1172</span><span class="r">case</span> primary_key_prefix_type</p>
  <p>Hello <b>cool</b> world #42!</p>
</body>'

html.search('p').each{ |para| wrap_text(para) }
puts html.at('body')
#=> <body>
#=>   <p><span class="no">1172</span><span class="r">case</span> <span>primary_key_prefix_type</span></p>
#=>   <p><span>Hello</span> <b>cool</b> <span>world</span> <span>#42!</span></p>
#=> </body>
```

**Edit**: More examples:

```
# If your lines don't have element wrapping them...
raw = [
  '<span class="no">1172</span><span class="r">case</span> primary_key',
  'Hello <b>cool</b> world #42!'
]
puts raw.map{ |line| wrap_text(Nokogiri::HTML(line).at('body')).inner_html }
#=> <span class="no">1172</span><span class="r">case</span> <span>primary_key</span>
#=> <p>Hello <b>cool</b> world #42!</p>

# If your lines each have exactly one element wrapping them...
wrapped = [
  '<a><span class="no">1172</span><span class="r">case</span> primary_key</a>',
  '<b>Hello <b>cool</b> world #42!</b>'
]
body = Nokogiri::HTML(wrapped.join("\n")).at('body')
puts body.children.map{ |e| wrap_text(e) }
#=> <a><span class="no">1172</span><span class="r">case</span> <span>primary_key</span></a>
#=> <b><span>Hello</span> <b>cool</b> <span>world</span> <span>#42!</span></b>
```

Comment: but you've added the 'p' tags, is it possible to iterate through lines?

Comment: @megas What are 'lines' in an HTML/XML document? Is your sample content exactly all the text that you have? There is no owning context?

Comment: Actually I have a lot of those lines generated by CodeRay. It has beginning and ending tags, but inside there are those lines or rows.

Comment: @megas I've updated my answer with more examples for how to convert what you may or may not have into what you want.